# How to handle different creator type models for post creator in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have Profile, Post, Teacher and Student Django models, I created Profile model to share the common fields that Teacher and Student have.

**Question:** **what is the right way to represent the creator relationship in the post model, and if my following code right, How I can identify the type of the Profile I mean if it's teacher or student, when I get the profile instance from post creator?**:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    .
    .

class Post(models.Model):
    .
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    .

class Teacher(models.Model):
    .
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile)
    .

class Student(models.Model):
    .
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile)
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database design and model relationship is not really in line, first of all , you need to rename your Porfile to Profile, then in the custom student Model you make sure you declare the needed fields , then add it as foreign key creator for Post, then for teacher .. you need to add extra privileges to your users so that you treat Teacher as an administrator ..so instead you can just create custom User model then add neccessary and attach permissions to Teachers .. for more clarification am always online to help .. reach out to me via 08082182438  in watsap or dm

Comment: thank you for your answer, but here I'm not asking about permissions, the idea is how I can get the profile type (teacher or student) when I get the creator from post instance.

Answer (score 0):

To distinguish between the teacher and student profiles, it could be handled by combining the `related_name` and `hasattr`:

```
 class Teacher(models.Model):
    .
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, related_name='teacher')
    .

class Student(models.Model):
    .
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, related_name='school')
    .
```

Then getting the profile type from post creator instance as here:

```
profile = post.creator

if hasattr(profile_instance,'teacher'):
    teacher = profile.teacher
elif hasattr(profile_instance,'student'):
    student = profile.student
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USER_ROLES = (
        ('Teacher', 'Teacher'),
        ('Student', 'Student'),
    )

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(choices=USER_ROLES, max_length=10)
```

**In views you can achieve this functionality like this**

For creating student profile :

```
student_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=student_user, role='Student')

#Now creating post instance for particular user_type
my_post = Post.objects.create(creator=student_profile, <here your other attributes>)
```

**Similarly, you can do it for others user_type**

Comment: I thought about this solution but you can't have different attributes for each type, the idea behind different model types is to have different attributes for each type.